# MySQL - conditional select in group

Tags: mysql, sql, select, group-by, conditional-statements

I have a simple table with several rows and I would like to group them by `id_room` and select value only when condition is true. Problem is that condition is always false even there is a row with right date column `year_month`.

Here is schema:

```
CREATE TABLE tbl_account_room (
  `id` int, 
  `year_month` date, 
  `value` int,
  `id_room` int
);

INSERT INTO tbl_account_room
    (`id`, `year_month`, `value`, `id_room`)
VALUES
    (1, '2016-08-01', 1, 300),
    (2, '2016-09-01', 2, 300),
    (3, '2016-10-01', 3, 300);
```

and here query:

```
SELECT 
  (case when '2016-10-01' = ar.year_month then ar.value else 0 end) as total
FROM tbl_account_room AS ar
WHERE ar.year_month >= "2016-08-01"
  AND ar.year_month <= "2016-11-01"
  and ar.id_room = '300'
GROUP BY ar.id_room
LIMIT 10
```

Here is [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/60eca6/1/0)

In column `total` I'm getting 0 and I would like to get value 3 because `year_month` is `2016-10-01`. Why this happens?

Answer (score 1):

You certainly don't need that `CASE` condition and include that condition in your `WHERE` clause rather like

```
SELECT 
ar.value as total,
GROUP_CONCAT(ar.year_month)
FROM tbl_account_room AS ar
WHERE ar.year_month = '2016-10-01'
GROUP BY ar.id_room;
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why you want the result like that, here you can use self join to do that:

```
SELECT 
  MAX(t1.value) as total,
  GROUP_CONCAT(ar.year_month)
FROM tbl_account_room AS ar
LEFT JOIN tbl_account_room AS t1
ON ar.id_room = t1.id_room
AND ar.year_month = t1.year_month
AND t1.year_month = '2016-10-01'
WHERE ar.year_month >= "2016-08-01"
  AND ar.year_month <= "2016-11-01"
  and ar.id_room = '300'
GROUP BY ar.id_room
LIMIT 10;
```

and here is [**SQLFiddle Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/60eca6/7).